# Vue: same route same component, but different params

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a SPA where after each HTTP response, the app goes to the same component with the same route, but the props passed to the component will be different based on the response. I understand the reuse feature in Vue and it won't reload. But I need the newly returned data every time I trigger the router to go to the component. My app.vue:

```
upload(formData).then(x => {
    router.push({
        name: 'Chart',
        params: {
            chartData: x
        }
    });
});
```

Then the target Chart.vue:

```
props: ['chartData'],
data: function() {
    // do some processing using props
    return {...}
}
```

My problem is that since for my router, the route doesn't change, hence other approaches like using :key=$route.fullPath or the beforeRouteUpdate don't work. Then how can I make the Chart component recompute the data? I've checked thru **computed()** and **watch** as well but it's not working.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701175/is-it-possible-to-change-props-value-from-method-in-vue-component