# VueJS: Altering prop directly vs. this.[prop] in v-if

Tags: vue.js

I built a vue component that get's a number value via prop from the outside laravel blade, like this:

```
<my-custom-template :mynumber="{{$numbervalue}}" :list:{{$alist}}></my-custom-template>
```

inside the template I have a v-for list and the prop:

```
props:{
     list:Array,
     mynumber: Number,
    [..]
}
```

and

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in list">{{item}}<span v-if="item.id == mynumber">active</span></li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Whenever the ID of the item is the same as the value *mynumber*, I want the "active" tag/span to be displayed.

Now in this template I also have a method that sends an axios request and on success it alters the value of the prop "mynumber", so the list should rerender:

```
axios.post('/api/someurl', this.obj)
            .then(res => {
                this.mynumber= res.data[something]; // returns a new number from the db.
                        })
                .catch(error => { [..]
                };
```

**Issue:** If I use *this.mynumber* in the list's v-if condition, the "active" tag is never being shown. If I use directly *== mynumber* then it works, but I cannot alter it with the axios response.
How should I approach this correctly? 
How can I alter the initial prop, with the new value from the axios call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be modifying props directly, [as mentioned in this prior Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701175/is-it-possible-to-change-props-value-from-method-in-vue-component).

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "propRoomSelected"

Second, [as seen in the Vue documentation for conditionals](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), you do not use `this` within templates, the `this` is inferred.

Now, to get to the meat of your question, how to look at **either** a prop or a new value when rendering. Here's how I'd do it.

```
<template>
  <ul>
      <li v-for="item in list">{{item}}<span v-if="isCurrent(item.id)">active</span></li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['list', 'myNumber'],
  data() {
    return {
      myNewNumber: undefined
    }
  },

  methods: {
    isCurrent(itemId) {
      return itemId == (myNewNumber || myNumber)
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**Edit:**

Note that there is a difference between

```
return itemId == (myNewNumber || myNumber)
```

and

```
return (itemId == myNewNumber) || (itemId == myNumber)
```

The first one "short circuits" a comparison against `myNumber` once `myNewNumber` becomes anything "truthy". [Read more here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-evaluation-3709ffda6384).

Comment: Interesting solution. If I check for itemId == (myNewNumber || myNumber) won't I have 2 "active" tags in the list then, the one with the initial value and the new one? I would like to have only the most recent one as "active".

Comment: Nope! The `(myNewNumber || myNumber)` bit will only return the original number if `myNewNumber` remains undefined. Read my edit above

Comment: ah ok, sounds good to me :) But now with this I get "_vm.isCurrent is not a function" in the console. I tried in "computed: {" with "isCurrent: function(itemId)" as well as with "isCurrent(itemId)" but no luck there. In template the check is: " v-if="isCurrent(item.id)""

Comment: Ah! Sorry, it should be a method, not a computed. Fixed above.

Comment: Yes! That's it, thank you @Lanny Bose, it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mutate props directly. Use `this.$emit` (Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) instead to change the myNumber in the parent. myNumber will then automatically update in the child component.

Comment: I see, the method emits "update" and the $updatedvalue to the parent and the parent changes the props value @update. Would that look like this in the laravel blade then: <my-custom-template :mynumber="{{$numbervalue}}" :list:{{$alist}} @update="$numbervalue = $updatedvalue"></my-custom-template> ?

Comment: To be perfectly honestly I have never worked with laravel before but that's the general idea, yes. You don't want to duplicate the state in the child. It would be `@update="$numbervalue = $event"` though. The props passed to the top are always $event (In straight up Vue, no idea how laravel blade changes the $ syntax, sorry!). Once your parent changed the variable, the child will reflect those changes

Comment: no worries, it was helpful nonetheless :) I think I'm on the right track.