# How to change props in child component created using v-for in VueJs 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, publish-subscribe, vue-events

I have a **parent component** creating child components using `v-for` directive:

```html
<div class="planlist">
    <ul id="planOl">
    <PlanLego
    v-for="action in store.plan"
        :v-if="action !== activeStep"
        :action_id="action.act_id"
        :actor="action.actor"
        :blocked="action.blocked"
        :key="action.act_id"
        @choose="planClick"
        @fix="changeActor"
    />
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I'm emitting a signal **from the child component**:

```js
this.$emit('fix', {
     act_id: this.action_id,
     actor: this.actor
});
```

#### My question is:

how can I access and change the properties (for example `actor`) of this specific child component that emitted the signal? thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have updated values of `act_id` and `actor` in the child itself  then why do you want to emit and pass it again from parent ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43701284) changing the property value from inside the component will generate a warning, and instead, they suggested emitting a signal.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You want to update the `actor` for the specific child in the parent component based on the `act_id` passed from child. If Yes, You can achieve this by iterating the original array object in the parent.

In the parent component, Your `changeActor` method should be like this **:**

In template **:**

```
@fix="changeActor($event)"
```

In script **:**

```
changeActor(emittedObj) {
    store.plan.forEach(item => {
        if (item.act_id === emittedObj.act_id) {
            item.actor = emittedObj.actor
        }
    });
}
```